# jquery vertical div scrolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am looking for a vertical div content scroller that will paly continues and auto the content of a div. No buttons needed only pause on mouse over.

I have found a nice one but is horizontal http://www.maaki.com/thomas/SmoothDivScroll/

Any suggestion for jquery plugin that achieves the above?

Comment: Tweek[modify] the plugin and make it scroll Vertical

Comment: I agree, just get inside the main js file and find where it scrolls horizontally and make it do vertical. Otherwise this would be pretty straightforward to build in jquery from scratch as well.